# createBackgroundMedia method does not work for URL and for local file

Tags: codenameone

I think there is a problem with createBackgroundMedia() method. This simple following code does not work.

```
TextArea log=new TextArea(10,5); 

        Button b=new Button("Play");
        b.addActionListener(evt->{
            Display.getInstance().scheduleBackgroundTask(() -> {

                try{
                      Media audio = MediaManager.createBackgroundMedia("http://live2.vestaradio.com/RSL");
                      audio.prepare();
                      audio.play();

                } catch(IOException err){
                    ToastBar.showErrorMessage("Erreur du streaming audio: ");
                }
            });

            String logs=NativeLogs.getNativeLogs();

            log.setText(logs);
        });

        hi.add(b);
        hi.add(contenu);
```

I use the Native Log cn1lib to get logging text. I hope it can help to find the issue:

```
--------- beginning of main
10-12 15:23:28.555  1221  1261 D OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 103079215104
10-12 15:23:28.570  1319  1319 W EDT     : type=1400 audit(0.0:1356): avc: denied { search } for name="bin" dev="mmcblk0p20" ino=228481 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:wland_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
--------- beginning of system
10-12 15:23:28.597  1221  1221 V ActivityThread: SVC-Creating service CreateServiceData{token=android.os.BinderProxy@1e4de83 className=com.codename1.media.AudioService packageName=eric.dodji.app intent=null}
10-12 15:23:28.597  1221  1221 D CN1     : onCreate
10-12 15:23:28.599  1221  1221 D ActivityThread: SVC-Calling onStartCommand: com.codename1.media.AudioService@690d800, flags=0, startId=1
10-12 15:23:28.616  1221  1221 D CN1     : http://live2.vestaradio.com/RSL
10-12 15:23:28.618  1221  1221 W MediaPlayer: Couldn't open http://live2.vestaradio.com/RSL: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://live2.vestaradio.com/RSL
10-12 15:23:28.621  1221  1221 D MPlugin : com.mediatek.common.media.IOmaSettingHelperClazz exists on mapping table : true
10-12 15:23:28.621  1221  1221 V MPlugin : Create new path class loader (/vendor/plugin/FwkPlugin/FwkPlugin.apk)
10-12 15:23:28.632  1221  1221 D MPlugin : Load class : com.mediatek.op.media.DefaultOmaSettingHelper successfullyPathClassLoader :dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/vendor/plugin/FwkPlugin/FwkPlugin.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]]
10-12 15:23:28.638  1221  1221 W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app-lib/FwkPlugin
10-12 15:23:28.646  1221  1221 D MPlugin : Exception occurs when using constructor with Context
10-12 15:23:28.647  1221  1221 V DefaultOmaSettingHelper: setSettingHeader: with uri=http://live2.vestaradio.com/RSL
10-12 15:23:28.648  1221  1221 V DefaultOmaSettingHelper: isOMAEnabled: enabled=true
10-12 15:23:28.648  1221  1221 I DefaultOmaSettingHelper: setOmaSettingHeader(com.codename1.media.AudioService@690d800,null)
10-12 15:23:28.651  1221  1221 V DefaultOmaSettingHelper: setOmaSettingHeader: params:minUdpPort=1024minUdpPort=1024maxUdpPort=65535rtspProxyEnable=0rtspProxyHost=nullrtspProxyPort=-1httpProxyEnable=0httpProxyHost=nullhttpProxyPort=-1httpBufferSize=10rtspBufferSize=4
10-12 15:23:28.670  1221  1221 D MediaPlayer: Don't notify duration to eric.dodji.app!
10-12 15:23:28.683  1221  1297 D MediaHTTPConnection: disconnect finish
10-12 15:23:28.695  1221  1252 D NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
10-12 15:23:30.364  1221  1252 D libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: live2.vestaradio.com get result from proxy gai_error = 0
10-12 15:23:30.365  1221  1252 I System.out: [socket][0] connection live2.vestaradio.com/149.202.186.135:80;LocalPort=-1(30000)
10-12 15:23:30.366  1221  1252 D         : [Posix_connect Debug]Process eric.dodji.app :80
10-12 15:23:33.051  1221  1252 I System.out: [socket][/10.161.159.49:58041] connected
10-12 15:23:33.052  1221  1252 I System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
10-12 15:23:33.053  1221  1252 I System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
10-12 15:23:34.098  1221  1252 D MediaHTTPConnection: mTotalSize=-1
10-12 15:23:39.607  1221  1221 D MediaPlayer: setSubtitleAnchor in MediaPlayer
10-12 15:23:39.652  1221  1221 D MediaPlayer: handleMessage msg:(1, 0, 0)
10-12 15:23:39.697  1221  1261 D OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 12 upload: x, y, width height = 0, 0, 1024, 504
10-12 15:23:39.713  1221  1316 E MediaPlayer: prepareAsync called in state 8, mPlayer(0xabb9c7e0)
10-12 15:23:39.737  1221  1316 D TestBackgroundMusic: [Task Thread] 0:0:12,653 - Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException - null
10-12 15:23:39.738  1221  1316 W System.err: java.lang.IllegalStateException
10-12 15:23:39.754  1221  1316 W System.err: at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepareAsync(Native Method)
10-12 15:23:39.754  1221  1316 W System.err: at com.codename1.media.AudioService$a.q_(AudioService.java:232)
10-12 15:23:39.754  1221  1316 W System.err: at com.codename1.media.d.q_(MediaProxy.java:53)
10-12 15:23:39.754  1221  1316 W System.err: at eric.dodji.app.a.d(MyApplication.java:76)
10-12 15:23:39.754  1221  1316 W System.err: at eric.dodji.app.d.run(Unknown Source)
10-12 15:23:39.754  1221  1316 W System.err: at com.codename1.o.q$1.run(Display.java:740)
10-12 15:23:39.754  1221  1316 W System.err: at com.codename1.impl.b$1.run(CodenameOneThread.java:60)
10-12 15:23:39.754  1221  1316 W System.err: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
10-12 15:23:40.818  1221  1261 D OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 12 upload: x, y, width height = 0, 74, 1024, 73
10-12 15:23:40.834  1221  1261 D OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 12 upload: x, y, width height = 0, 388, 1024, 38
10-12 15:23:40.869  1221  1261 D OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 12 upload: x, y, width height = 0, 73, 1024, 417
10-12 15:23:40.884  1221  1261 D OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 12 upload: x, y, width height = 0, 425, 1024, 37
10-12 15:23:40.983  1221  1261 D OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 12 upload: x, y, width height = 0, 0, 1024, 39
10-12 15:23:40.999  1221  1261 D OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 12 upload: x, y, width height = 0, 83, 1024, 37
10-12 15:23:41.540  1221  1261 D OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 34359738369
10-12 15:23:41.541  1221  1261 D OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 34359738368
10-12 15:23:44.570  1340  1340 W EDT     : type=1400 audit(0.0:1357): avc: denied { search } for name="bin" dev="mmcblk0p20" ino=228481 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:wland_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
10-12 15:23:44.594  1221  1221 D ActivityThread: SVC-Calling onStartCommand: com.codename1.media.AudioService@690d800, flags=0, startId=2
10-12 15:23:44.599  1221  1221 D CN1     : http://live2.vestaradio.com/RSL
10-12 15:23:44.599  1221  1221 W MediaPlayer: Couldn't open http://live2.vestaradio.com/RSL: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: http://live2.vestaradio.com/RSL
10-12 15:23:44.600  1221  1221 D MPlugin : com.mediatek.common.media.IOmaSettingHelperClazz exists on mapping table : true
10-12 15:23:44.600  1221  1221 V MPlugin : Get cached path class loader (/vendor/plugin/FwkPlugin/FwkPlugin.apk)
10-12 15:23:44.600  1221  1221 D MPlugin : Load class : com.mediatek.op.media.DefaultOmaSettingHelper successfullyPathClassLoader :dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/vendor/plugin/FwkPlugin/FwkPlugin.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]]
10-12 15:23:44.601  1221  1221 D MPlugin : Exception occurs when using constructor with Context
10-12 15:23:44.601  1221  1221 V DefaultOmaSettingHelper: setSettingHeader: with uri=http://live2.vestaradio.com/RSL
10-12 15:23:44.601  1221  1221 V DefaultOmaSettingHelper: isOMAEnabled: enabled=true
10-12 15:23:44.601  1221  1221 I DefaultOmaSettingHelper: setOmaSettingHeader(com.codename1.media.AudioService@690d800,null)
10-12 15:23:44.602  1221  1221 V DefaultOmaSettingHelper: setOmaSettingHeader: params:minUdpPort=1024minUdpPort=1024maxUdpPort=65535rtspProxyEnable=0rtspProxyHost=nullrtspProxyPort=-1httpProxyEnable=0httpProxyHost=nullhttpProxyPort=-1httpBufferSize=10rtspBufferSize=4
10-12 15:23:44.606  1221  1221 D MediaPlayer: Don't notify duration to eric.dodji.app!
```

I use a web radio streaming URL. According to the log, createBackgroundMedia() method have to know the duration of the content to play. Is it the reason of the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a file URL for that method. `jar:` URL's work only on the browser. Something like this (untested) should generally work (assuming static CN import):

```
String fileName = getAppHomePath() + "music.mp3";
try(InputStream in = getResourceAsStream("/music.mp3"),
      OutputStream o = openFileOutputStream(fileName)) {
   Util.copy(in, o);
   Media audio = MediaManager.createBackgroundMedia(fileName);
   audio.play();
} catch(IOException e) {
    Log.e(e);
    // ... handle error
}
```

Comment: Hi Shai,This answer is not what i need. I think there is a bug or a regression in the createBackgroundMedia() method. You have to check and test my example. It works well with the simulator but not on the device. the same example does not work with an URL. I need to use it with an URL and not with a local file. Both of them does not work on the device with this method. This is why i'am talking about a regression or a bug.

Comment: The jar URL isn't meant to work so it's irrelevant if it works on the simulator. That's probably an implementation detail. Background media should work with an HTTP/HTTPS URL depending on the data you submit. If it doesn't please update your question with the log for an https URL. Please try to place the log as a code block so it will be more readable. Then comment here to notify me of the update

Comment: Hi Shai, i updated the log and formatted it so you can read it. I use a web radio streaming URL. According to the log, createBackgroundMedia() method have to know the duration of the content to play. Is it the reason of the issue? i don't know. Check the log and tell me. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how well radio streaming works with these API's. Does it work if you use the play in foreground API?

Comment: In that case it might be a limitation in the background media API, you can file an issue with that test case and we'll investigate whether this is feasible in Android

Comment: Ok Shai! i will file an issue about that. Thanks!